# How to check the information from the database using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to use my own API to check the information about email and password, but I don't know how to do that. Anything information that I put show up "Login" but I need to just show up "Login" if the information was the same that I registered in my database.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const Login = () => {
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const info = {email, password}
        
        fetch('http://localhost:3333/login/', {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(info)
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            console.log("login")

        }).catch(() => {
            console.log("NO")
        })
    }

    return ( 
        <div className="all ">

        <div className='button d-flex justify-content-center '>
        <Link to="/" className="text-center btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-4">Login</Link>
        <Link to="/register" className="text-center btn btn-secondary btn-lg m-4">Register</Link>
        </div>
                
            <p className='text-center'>Sign With:</p>
        
        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="email" value = {email} onChange={(e) => setEmail (e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter email" required/>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" value = {password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
        </div>
            </div>
     );
}
 
export default Login;
```

My API is shown below and it's working fine and the login function is verifying well

```
const {
    PrismaClient
} = require("@prisma/client");

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {
    async createUser(req, res) {
        try {
            const {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                email,
                password,
                age,
                role
            } = req.body

            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
            console.log(salt)

            const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
            console.log(hash)

            const verifyemail = await prisma.UserInfo.findUnique({
                where: {
                    email
                }
            })

            if (verifyemail) {
                return res.json({
                    error: "there is a email with the same name, please change."
                })
            }

            const user = await prisma.UserInfo.create({
                data: {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    email: email,
                    password: hash,
                    age: age,
                    role: role
                }
            });

            return res.json(user)

        } catch (error) {
            return res.json({
                error
            })

        }
    },

    async login(req, res) {
        try {

            const {email, password} = req.body

            const user = await prisma.UserInfo.findUnique({
                where: {
                    email : req.body.email
                }
            })  
            
            if(user)  {
                const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                if(match) {
                    return res.send("login")
                }
                else {
                    return res.send("There is something wrong with your password")
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return res.json({
                error
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say show up "Login", do you mean the `Login` link, the "login" `console.log` or the `Login` component?

Comment: Login should be When the informations( email and password ) were right it will show up "Login" in my console and if is wrong doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have understood from your question is that, no matter what username and password you are entering you are always ending up in the `.then` block, while if the username/password is wrong it should go to the `catch` block.

If I have understood that correctly, I would suggest updating your node code to handle this scenario. Fetch will only go in catch if there is a network error or CORS error, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

With this, I would suggest you can add an else block in your Node code and add

```
return res.status(401).send("Icorrect password");
```

after this, in front end code, you can add

```
.then(response => /* check response status code and throw 'Incorrect' if 401 */ )
```

Comment: I changed this code and when submit I have the error "Network response was not OK" maybe My problem is because the respose.ok is false and my api is not working for that reason, now I'm trying to figure out why my response.ok is false
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Network response was not OK');     
        }).then((responseJson) => {
            console.log("Your're loggin in")
            return responseJson
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)

Comment: If you are using express you can do `res.sendStatus( 401 )` the response.ok will be true for all responses (200-299) since you are not sending status, your reponse.ok is always true. check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok